# Decoded circe array inside case class always failing case class comparison test?

Tags: scala, circe

For this case class:

```
import io.circe.generic.JsonCodec

@JsonCodec
case class Stuff(things: Array[String])
```

This test passes ok (case class to json test):

```
import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.syntax._
import org.scalatest._

val caseClass = Stuff(things = Array("one", "two"))

val json = caseClass.asJson.spaces2

json shouldEqual
      """{
         | "things" : [
         |   "one",
         |   "two"
         | ]
         |}""".stripMargin
```

However, this is failing (json to case class test)

```
import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.syntax._
import org.scalatest._

val json =
      """{
         | "things" : [
         |   "one",
         |   "two"
         | ]
         |}""".stripMargin

val caseClass = Right(decode[Stuff](json))

caseClass shouldEqual Stuff(things = Array("one", "two"))
```

Stepping through it in a debugger, it seems that the array doesn not get decoded as I would expect, it seems to be the object identity/memory address, which is always different, and so my test is failing:

[Ljava.lang.String;@2fa7ae9

Note this just seems to happen for Arrays, there is lots more stuff in my json blob that I have left out for this example - Maps and nested case-classes all get decoded and can be compared ok, its only when Arrays are added that the comparison fails - am I missing something?

Comment: That is not how you are supposed to compare Arrays. Just compare the elements inside the array. And use `equals` for comparing those strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a Scala issue (or a ScalaTest issue) than a circe one. Scala's `==` method on arrays uses reference equality, and while ScalaTest's `shouldEqual` will work "correctly" on arrays (i.e. it'll compare contents rather than references), it will still use `==` for array members when comparing two case class instances.

There are lots of ways you could work around this: by writing your own [`Equality` instance](http://doc.scalactic.org/3.0.1/#org.scalactic.Equality) for `Stuff`, by comparing `caseClass.things shouldEqual Array("one", "two")`, etc. Having a mutable collection (like `Array`) as a case class member is not idiomatic Scala and is almost certainly a bad idea, though, and I'd strongly suggest fixing this issue by changing it to something like `List` or `Vector`.

Comment: Thanks, changing Array to List in the case class works for me.